# Why does ggplot2 continue working but not output anything?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

### Reprex

```
install.packages("tidyverse") ## general use and data cleaning
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(here)
library(hms)
library(scales)
library(rstudioapi)
install.packages("ggmap")
library(ggmap)

ggplot(data = bikeshare_v8) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = ride_id,
                           y = ride_length))
```

### Task

Analyzing the divvy bikeshare data for the google data analytics course, finding differences between members and casuals.

### Problem

Though previously the data could be plotted without incident, ggplot will no longer work. The code chunk still has the left side green bar, and the spinning progress circle is still present in the Rmarkdown output below the code chunk. While this is happening, RAM use keeps accumulating, but even after minutes nothing displayed and the code does not complete.

### Solutions Attempted

- running with only `tidyverse` installed and loaded - no change
- running without the project being loaded - just markdown - no change
- making sure windows defender is excluded from R files - no change

***Why did this work before, but not now?*
*How can I get ggplot to work again?***

Comment: Sometimes with various packages and updates not everything is compatible. You may try deleting and redownloading R or downloading the previous version of R or the tidyverse package.

Comment: if it is a very large dataset, it can take a long time to render. Try something like `ggplot(data = slice(bikeshare_v8, 100))` to see the first part of the data and check everything is working

Comment: Although you start the question with the word "REPREX", this question is NOT reproducible, as we do not have access to the "bikeshare_8" dataset. Please share it as code with `dput(bikeshare_v8)`

Comment: My first step would be to check whether this only occurs in `rmarkdown`.

Comment: A very common issue is related to having intermediate objects with the same name in the rmarkdown file AND the global environment. Running the code in a fresh session solves many similar cases

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution - *wrong datatype*

Lubridate was used to convert the time information to the *duration* datatype, which ggplot did not like.

Converting to numeric datatype using `as.numeric` solved the issue.